# Converting Pandas Series to Set splits values in series with commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm new to Pandas. I want to take some strings returned from pandas series (a bunch of values under a column in a csv named 'lots') and put them in a set. To this end I wrote the following:

```
setbincsv_df = bincsv_df['lots'].apply(set)
print(setbincsv_df )
```

But the output resulting from that print statement takes a value in that series like "OP" and displays it as  136    {P, O}. Not only does it not split it but it reverses it.

Bottom 5 items returned:

```
**"132    {I, F}"
"133    {E, F}"
"134    {W, I}"
"135    {V, H}"
"136    {P, O}"**
```

I'd expect it to return the value as it was in the series "OP". Why is this happening?

Comment: `.apply(set)` is creating a set for each row from the string values.  Does this do what you want?  `setbincsv_df = set(bincsv_df['lots'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use apply you are applying the set operation to the string of each row.
For example if you have the word "pull"

```
print(set("pull"))
{'p','u','l'}
```

what you probably want is to do set(series):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lots':['ai','cd','ai','drgf']})


print(set(df['lots']) )
```

that outputs

```
{'cd', 'ai', 'drgf'}
```